# ¿Cómo pasar de DateTime a TimeStamp en Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

Recibo un dataframe con un tipo datetime, y debo meter ese campo a una función que necesita sea timestamp.

Tengo

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 22 entries, 0 to 21
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------          --------------  -----         
 0   User            22 non-null     category      
 1   Follows         22 non-null     category      
 2   Following_Time  22 non-null     datetime64[ns]
dtypes: category(2), datetime64[ns](1)
```

Como digo necesito que sea en TimeStamp. Lo he intentando con astype y con pd.timestamp

¿cómo pasarlo?

Gracias.

NOTA: El compañero Mauricio me ha mandado un link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881876/python-pandas-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-effectively-through-dt-accessor/40881958#40881958 con respuestas muy interesantes. Una de ellas es hacer...

```
I think you should not use apply, simply astype would be fine:

df['ts'] = df.datetime.astype('int64') // 10**9
```

Os muestro las respuestas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aplico el método.

```
relations['Following_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(relations['Following_Time'],infer_datetime_format=True).astype('int64') // 10**9
```

y obtengo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es así correcto?, gracias.

Comment: Seguramente [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40881876/python-pandas-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-effectively-through-dt-accessor/40881958#40881958) te sirva. Por cierto, la ubiqué con [esta búsqueda](https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=datetime+to+timestamp+pandas). Saludos

Comment: Pues la verdad es que ESA respuesta no lo ví. Vi otros y no lo tengo claro, la verdad. Veo que habla de varios metodos. De aplicar apply y lamda, pero eso es lo de menos. ¿Cómo lo he de entender?. ¿dividir simplemente un datetime?  Muchas gracias Mauricio

Comment: Al hacer el cast de `datetime` a `int64`, te dará el valor en `ns` (nanosegundos). Luego, `timestamp` puede recibir un parámetro que indica el tipo de valor recibido, por ejemplo: `pd.timestamp(df.datetime.values.astype(np.int64), unit='ns')`. Más información en la [documentación](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) . Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Pues parece que es así.
He realizado la operación contraria con un ejemplo. Y me da mismo valor.

He cogido uno de los valores que en la pregunta tenía como timestamp y he realizado su coversión a datetime de nuevo.

```
print (datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1560405598))  # prueba
2019-06-13 05:59:58
```

pasos que he seguido.

1. tengo una columna con datetime
2. me la paso a timestamp
3. un valor de timestamp lo vuelvo a pasar a datetime para ver que es correcto.

Comment: Daniel, tu respuesta parece un comentario. Te sugiero que la edites y expliques con más detalle la solución. De esa forma servirá para otros usuarios que tengan un problema similar. Puedes leer [answer]. Y pasadas 24 horas, puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta como válida. Saludos